# Where does the value for __name__ come from?

Tags: python, django, logging

So I have a several of django settings files, one for testing, others for different customers.

None of these settings files change `sys.path` at all.

All of them include a singular base settings file that contains `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Most of the files have code that does this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.error("Something went wrong")
```

In my test settings files, the module `__name__` looks like `saml.xyz` so the logger.name is `saml.xyz` but when I use a different settings files, the module `__name__` looks like `apps.saml.xyz` which makes the logger.name `apps.saml.xyz`.

This causes some log messages to be missed because the handler is connected to the wrong place.  A handler for `saml.xyz` will not get messages for `apps.saml.xyz` and vice versa.  All the routing is based on the configured logger/handler including the **apps.** portion or not.

So how does python decide which `__name__` to give a file, and how could my different settings files affect that `__name__` without changing sys.path?

The commands are otherwise identical:

```
python manage.py test --settings=projectname.test saml
```

which yields

```
>>> logger.name
'saml.xyz'
```

or

```
python manage.py test --settings=projectname.customer saml
```

which yields

```
>>> logger.name
'apps.saml.xyz'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__name__` is the name under which the current module was imported.

If the module was imported with `import saml.xyz`, `__name__` reflects that directly. If you sometimes see `apps.saml.xyz` then your module was imported using *that* name, and there are two copies of your module loaded in memory; Python sees the two as separate.

You should avoid importing nested modules; use *only* the top-level name. Stick to either `apps.saml.xyz` or `saml.xyz`, but if the latter must be used, make sure `apps/` is *not* a package and is not itself listed on the python module search path `sys.path`.

Comment: So I went thru the whole project replacing `from apps.` with `from `, so that problem is wasn't possible.  It still happened.  Then I thought about INSTALLED_APPS, removed the `apps.` from there and the problem is solved.  I still have no idea how the different settings files could cause this though.  Since it INSTALLED APPS was common and no apps are imported from the settings module.

Comment: @Mark0978: This means that both the `apps/` directory itself *and* it's parent directory are listed in `sys.path`, and that there is a `__init__.py` file *in* `apps/`. This makes `apps` work both as a package *and* a top-level directory for Python to find modules in, and you don't want to have both. It leads to errors like these.

Comment: So I should put the `from apps.` back and make sure `apps/` is NOT in the python path?  I actually prefer the `apps.` in the import to point out which are part of this project only vs external apps.

Comment: That'd be the other alternative, yes. Keep `apps` as the top-level package, and make sure only it's parent directory is listed in `sys.path` and not `apps/` itself.